# Fail to open terminal from desktop but not from nautilus

Tags: command-line, python, nautilus

I'm trying to open a terminal from my desktop through the shortcut Ctr+Alt+T, icon or mousse right-bottom "Open in terminal" but it fails (it gets stuck like trying to open and eventually does not).
However if I go to Nautilus to open a folder and in a folder I press mousse right-bottom "Open in terminal" then it will open the terminal in my folder and then I can operate with the terminal as usual.

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and recently installed python 3.10, but already set as default python my python 3.10 and set python as python3.10 (that is python --version returns python 3.10.13).

Do anyone know whats happening here? Because I'm actually able to open my terminal but not as I wished which is with a shortcut or without needing to get to a folder in Nautilus.

Thanks in advanced !!

Answer (score 2):

The reason could be that you have changed the default python version in your system

Open a virtual terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F3 and login with your username and password.
If your original python version was not removed, you should tell the system to use it again just type : `sudo update-alternatives --config python3`
Select the version 3.8, if provided.
If that doesn’t work, you may need to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Oh... Sorry it was a mistake

Comment: It prints only one config available python3.10, nothing to configure. I guess I ll need to reinstall...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem going back to the original state: I reinstalled python2 and 3 as default and set python3.8 as default for python3 and left python3.10 only when specified. So now when I ask "python --version" it prints "python3.8". With this the problem was solved.
Seemed that Ubuntu 20.04 does not cope with python3.10 easily or straightforward as I expected.
Thanks everyone for the answers.

Comment: No Linux system copes well when you change the **system wide** version of Python.  A lot of things are dependent on the systems using the version of Python **that was installed with the system**, and you should NEVER attempt removal of or changing the version of the installed System python default version because it will likely break your systems.